# Laravel Vue.js wont update file to server

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I'm currently developing a website using Laravel 5.4 and Vue.js. I edited my Example.vue file a couple hours ago and uploaded it to my server using Filezilla, and all worked fine. But not that I have edited the file, and tried to upload it to the server again, the webserver displays the .vue file as the old one, and not the new one.

I have tried clearing both computer cache and server/laravel cache, but nothing happens.. I run both  `npm run dev` and `npm run watch` and I do not get any errors.

When I inspect element on my website I get an error saying:`TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined`, but this has been fixed in the app.js located in resources/assets/js by adding the line Vue.use(require('vue-resource'));, but I still get the same error, and the same view as I did before I updated..

The first time I updated the file, I only wanted it to display a `Hello World` text, and after the update when I had implemented the loading function for vue and div elements, it still shows up with the Hello World message...

This is my Example.vue file:

```js
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <p class="text-center" v-if="loading">
                Loading...
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            this.$http.get('/status/' + this.user_id )
            .then((resp) => {
                console.log(resp)
                this.status = resp.body.status
                this.loading = false
            })
        },
        props: ['user_id'],
        data() {
            return {
                status: '',
                loading: true
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Does anyone know that I can try to do? It's really frustrating when it's just the .vue file that won't update.. All other files works fine!

Comment: Did you clear your browser cache?

Comment: Yes, all cache was cleared, I got it working with the answer below!

Comment: please mark the answer from Alex Mac as accepted, as it solved your issue :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using laravel mix in your webpack.mix.js file. You install mix by adding mix to your package.json file. Then by running npm install on mac and on windows by running npm install --no-bin-links. Then by running npm run dev laravel mix will compile and update all of you resource assets to your public folder. see here https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mix.
 This will update all your vue components in your resources/assets/js/components folder which should hold all of your vue components. That should be it. If things are not updating you may have to run npm run watch or npm run watch-poll to catch updates as it will check for changes.

Mine looks like so:

webpack.mix.js:

```
const { mix } = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/assets/js');

mix.scripts([
    'resources/assets/js/enum_gender_select.js',
    'resources/assets/js/enum_title_select.js'
], 'public/assets/js/enum_select.js');


mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', '../resources/assets/css/sass.css');

mix.styles([
    'resources/assets/css/app.css',
    'resources/assets/css/sass.css'
], 'public/assets/css/all.css');
```

Homestead package.json file:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.15.3",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "cross-env": "^3.2.3",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "laravel-mix": "0.*",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "vue": "^2.1.10"
  }
}
```